# “admin/people” filters not available anymore

Tags: views

I have Drupal 8.7.3 so at admin side on people listing page I can't see the filter to find a particular user.

[image]

Comment: Does a view exist at `/admin/structure/views`  with: **View Name:** People, **Machine Name:** user_admin_people? (This is the default view display used for the admin/people page.) As @greggles alluded to, the most likely issue is that that view no longer exists or has been edited and its exposed filters removed.

Comment: I don't know why this question has downvotes. I wish those people who downvoted would explain why they did that in a constructive way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check:

1. Is the views module still enabled?
2. Is this specific view enabled?
3. Did the configuration get changed for the view that exists at admin/people?

For #1, go to the modules page and scroll down to views and confirm it is enabled.

For #2, I noticed that I was able to "Disable" the `user_admin_people` view and then I get a screen at `admin/people` that looks exactly like yours. The resolution to that problem is to go to `/admin/structure/views/` and "Enable" the `user_admin_people` view.

For #3, you could install a fresh version of Drupal 8.7.3 and compare the configurations of the view to find if it's wrong.

Comment: Yes the views module is enabled and not sure about the configuration because I am adding features and deploying it, in one of my old branch the filters are there but that's very old, the drupal version is the same in old and new branches

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit with a suggestion of how you might be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks by enabling user_admin_people this it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As greggles mentioned it, first thing is to check that the configuration of the view did not change.
Go to yoursite.com/admin/structure/views/view/user_admin_people and look for any exposed filters in the "Filter criteria" section (maybe your features altered the configuration).

Here is an example of Drupal default configuration for this view.

[image: filters of admin/people view]